# Twitch title change via api

Tags: twitch, http-status-code-410

I have a little chat bot for twitch and I want to make now a function where you can change the stream title.
My function looks at the moment so:

```
public changeTitle = (new_title: string, callback: any): void => {
    let t = this;
    let request = require('request');
    request.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + this.settings.current_channel + "?client_id="+this.settings.clientId, { json: true }, function (err, res) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            let current_title = res.body.status;
            console.log(current_title);
            let request2 = require('request');
            let options = {
                url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+t.settings.current_channel+"?channel[status]="+current_title+new_title,
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "OAuth "+t.settings.clientId,
                    "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json"
                }
            };
            request2.put(options, (error: Error, response: any, body: any): void => {
                console.log("Title changed?");
            });
        }
    });
};
```

in the `console.log(current_title)` I can see the current stream title.
After the `console.log("Title changed?")` nothing happened.
I get the error 410 GONE. So my way to change the title is no longer supported.
Can someone show me how to change the title?

Answer (score 0):

### This looks to be covered by [Update Channel](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/channels/#update-channel)

Specifically, rather than `channel[status]` use just `status` as a query param.

```
let options = {
            url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/"+t.settings.current_channel+"?status="+new_title,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "OAuth "+t.settings.clientId,
                "Accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json"
            }
```

You'll also need the `channel_editor` scope in order to use this on a given channel.

Comment: just add at the end of the url `&scopes=channel_editor` ?

Comment: Scopes are granted during authentication.  See here at the bottom: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/authentication/